# Determining whether the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1}(-1)^{n}\sqrt{n}$ is is Cesaro summable

Tags: real-analysis, cesaro-summable

In otherwords, whether the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum^{n}_{k=1}S_k$ exists, where $S_k$ is the $k$th partial sum. I'm not quite sure where to start with this one, especially since the sequence of terms $(-1,\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{3},\ldots)$ is Cesaro convergent to $0$, so I cannot invoke the argument that the sequence of terms doesn't converge to $0$ to show that the series is not Cesaro summable.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for pointing that out, fixed.

Comment: Edit: this question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896464/is-the-series-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt4-dots-summable?rq=1